# How do I get private data from the member functions? c++

Tags: c++, function, class, object, member

I am doing the Big c++ 2nd edition questions and I am on classes, I am stuck on a question. Basically I have to classes one called "person" and one called "Pemployee", I need to write the member functions of "Pemployee".

They gave me the declarations I need to implement the definitions.

What I don't get how to do is write call name, since it needs to call the private variable "person_data" which is a person object, I cannot access the string name directly but the member function of "person" has a "get_name" function which returns void, I dont understand how to get a string returned if I cannot return from the other definition.

Here are the two classes.

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(string pname, int page);
    void get_name() const;
    void get_age() const; //returns void
private:
    string name;
    int age; // 0 if unknown
};

class PEmployee
{
public:
    PEmployee();
    PEmployee(string employee_name, double initial_salary);
    void set_salary(double new_salary);
    double get_salary() const;
    string get_name() const; //assuming I need to call person get_name
private:
    Person person_data;
    double salary;
};
```

So once again, how do I call the "Pemployee" get_name to return the string name of the person_data private variable

Comment: Based on the code sample you have provided, there is no way to get `Person::name` from outside of the class (without cheating such as using global variables).

Comment: It doesnt make much sense having the getters void. get_name should return a string and get_age, int. Changing that, you should just call Person's get_name on PEmployee get_name

Comment: That is why I didn't get it, if get_name in the "person" object returned a string I could call the member function of that but it doesnt that is why I am confused, I am not sure if I don't understand a certain principle or if its a typo in the book...

Comment: It's probably a typo in the book. That happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help guy!

Comment: Also it should return the string by const reference if it is just returning a member, and pass those strings by const reference. The book looks questionable to me.

Comment: It has 'const' in the accessor functions to show that no private variables get changed, is that what you mean?

Comment: `const std::string& get_name() const` `void set_name(const std::string&)`

Comment: The book doesn't mention passing back const at this point, it said that having const after accessor functions prevents the programmer from changing the private variables in those functions.

Comment: for "const std::string& get_name() const" what does the const in the back mean?

Comment: `std::string get_name() const` returns a copy of the string, which is less efficient. `std::string& get_name() const` returns a reference to the string, allowing the caller to modify it. This won't compile actually, due to the second `const` protecting you. `const std::string& get_name() const` returns a reference to the string and prevents the caller from modifying it, so there's no risk they will poke your class and break it. But if the user does not make a copy of the result, when your member inside changes, so will the referencing string. Do not use this to return a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Typo in the book, `Person::get_name` should return string

Answer (score 0):

A lot of programming books teach you to add get and set methods to your classes when the variable needs to be read or modified from outside of the class.

You need to create get methods for each of the private variables that your want value access to outside of the class.

You will need a set methods if you want to change the values from outside the class.

Example get method for your class
`std::string get_name() const {return this->name;}`

Answer (score 0):

These signatures in the class called Person are pointless:

```
void get_name() const;
void get_age() const;
```

It is very probable that it is a typo. If it returned string then it whouldn't be pointless.

However if you would not like to change the functions signature or add a new memeber to the Person, then you should declare PEmployee as friend of Person, so member functions of PEmployee can reach private and protected members of Person. You can see below how to do this.

```
#include <string> 

class PEmployee;

class Person
{
public:
    friend PEmployee;
    Person(){ }
    Person(std::string pname, int page);
    void get_name() const;
    void get_age() const; //returns void
private:
    std::string name;
    int age; // 0 if unknown
};

class PEmployee
{
public:
    PEmployee();
    PEmployee(std::string employee_name, double initial_salary);
    void set_salary(double new_salary);
    double get_salary() const;
    std::string get_name() const; //assuming I need to call person get_name
private:
    Person person_data;
    double salary;
};
```